Deployment issues with .NET application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk - S3 permissions and Kestrel configuration errors
I am having trouble deploying my .NET application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Previously, I was able to deploy the application without issues, but after making some changes to the code and configuration, the deployment now fails and the environment is not responsive. Here are the details of my problem:
Observed Errors
S3 Permissions Errors:
Message: Access Denied: S3Bucket=elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-993506750413, S3Key=resources/environments/e-cdhckh2ijy/_runtime/_versions/ApiAiSoftware/V2
Message: One or more objects in the Elastic Beanstalk bucket could not be deleted. Verify that your S3 policies allow you to perform 's3:DeleteObject'.
Database Connection String Error:
Message: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'ai-software-ddbb.cgaslryjvp4n.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com;database'
Environment Status:
Environment is not responsive
S3 Bucket Policy

Steps I Have Tried
1.Review and Update Connection String: Verified and corrected the database connection string.
2.Configure Kestrel: Ensured Kestrel is configured to listen on port 5000.
3.Review S3 Permissions: Updated the S3 bucket permissions to include s3:DeleteObject.
What could be causing my Elastic Beanstalk environment to be unresponsive and for the deployment to fail with S3 permissions and connection string configuration errors? Are there any additional settings I should check or adjust?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
